# Loadbalancing/Redirecting from Kubernetes NodePort Services

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, webserver, load-balancing, haproxy

i got a bare metal cluster with a few nodeport deployments of my services (http and https). I would like to access them from a single url like myservices.local with (sub)paths.

config could be sth like the following (pseudo code):

```
/app1
http://10.100.22.55:30322
http://10.100.22.56:30322
# browser access: myservices.local/app1
/app2
https://10.100.22.55:31432
https://10.100.22.56:31432
# browser access: myservices.local/app2
/...
```

I tried a few things with haproxy and nginx but nothing really worked (for inexperienced in this webserver/lb things kinda confusing syntax/ config style in my opinion).

what is the easiest solution for a case like this?

Comment: please can you share `haproxy -vv` and the config

Comment: Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes, please consider to accept and upvote it. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most used way is to use a NGINX Ingress. The NGINX Ingress is built around the [Kubernetes Ingress resource](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ingress/), using a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#understanding-configmaps-and-pods) to store the NGINX configuration.

In the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress) we can read:

> [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/#ingress-v1beta1-networking-k8s-io) exposes HTTP and HTTPS routes from outside the cluster to [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) within the cluster. Traffic routing is controlled by rules defined on the Ingress resource.
>
> ```
>     internet
>         |    
>    [ Ingress ]    
>    --|-----|--    
>    [ Services ]
> ```
>
> An Ingress may be configured to give Services externally-reachable URLs, load balance traffic, terminate SSL / TLS, and offer name based virtual hosting. An  [Ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers) is responsible for fulfilling the Ingress, usually with a load balancer, though it may also configure your edge router or additional frontends to help handle the traffic.
>
> An Ingress does not expose arbitrary ports or protocols. Exposing services other than HTTP and HTTPS to the internet typically uses a service of type  [Service.Type=NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) or  [Service.Type=LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer).

This is exactly what you want to achieve.

The first thing you need to do is to install the NGINX Ingress Controller in your cluster. You can follow the official [Installation Guide](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/).

A ingress is always going to point to a Service. So you need to have a Deployment, a Service and a NGINX Ingress.

Here is an example of an application similar to your example.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
      app: app1
  name: app1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app1
        image: nginx
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
      app: app2
  name: app2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: app2
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: app2
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app2
        image: nginx
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5001
---          
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app1
  labels:
    app: app1
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    app: app1
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: app2
  labels:
    app: app2
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 5001
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5001
  selector:
    app: app2    
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress #ingress resource
metadata:
  name: myservices
  labels:
    app: myservices
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myservices.local #only match connections to myservices.local. 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /app1
        backend:
          serviceName: app1
          servicePort: 5000
      - path: /app2
        backend:
          serviceName: app2
          servicePort: 5001
```